# How to identify Spanish vs. English Text from a csv of tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, nlp

I'm trying to create a column that identifies English and Spanish tweets from a dataframe with several rows of tweets. Ideally tweets in English would be categorized as a 1 and those in Spanish would be marked as 0.

The end goal is to be able to filter out Spanish tweets from my dataframe to save English tweets in a new CSV. I looked at using Textblob, langdetect, and also fastText, but everything I've found gives instructions for just running the code on 1 string of text at a time.

Is there an easy way to categorize by language (English/Spanish) for a whole dataframe using Python?

Answer (score 1):

The `apply` method can be used in this case. Using `langdetect` as an example:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["hello, this is a tweet", "hola esto es un tweet"]})
>>> df["language"] = df["text"].apply(detect)
>>> df
                    text language
0  hello this is a tweet       en
1  hola esto es un tweet       es
```

or in your particular case if you want 0, 1 as indicators, you could do:

```py
>>> df["language"] = df["text"].apply(lambda x: (detect(x) == "en") * 1)
>>> df
                    text  language
0  hello this is a tweet         1
1  hola esto es un tweet         0
```

Comment: @GHOST5454 This is great thank you so much for sharing! I tried your code and it works perfectly, but I'm still having trouble running this with my own dataset which consists of 53,000+ rows.

For some reason I keep getting the following error message:

'LangDetectException: No features in text.'

Comment: I also found this article, https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect/issues/44

What I don't understand is how to apply exception handling of python,{try & catch}, the way the contributor describes.

Comment: Instead of using `lambda`, you can pass a function to `.apply` which has the try/except logic inside it! Consider running at first only against a subset of your df and displaying rows which don't parse to see if they have something unexpected in them (such as a numeric or `None` value)

Answer (score 0):

- I think there are two ways.

  i) to train a model to determine the text is Spanish or English using
  (NLP).

  ii) just trow the sentences to a list and use if condition with
  Spanish Character to give 1 or 0 on the bases of conditions.

  Hope it is helpful.